# Java generics - not within bounds

Tags: java, generics, type-bounds

I have following sample that cannot compile and produces `Error:() java: type argument GroupOfPartsDecorImpl<V> is not within bounds of type-variable GOP`. Code is the following:

```
class MainContainerGroupPartDecorator<V, GOP extends GroupOfParts<V, PartDecorator<V, ? extends Part<V>>>> 
extends BaseContainerGroupPartDecorator<V, GOP> {
    public static <V> MainContainerGroupPartDecorator<V, GroupOfPartsDecorImpl<V>> getInstance() {
        return null;
    }
}

class BaseContainerGroupPartDecorator<V, GOP extends GroupOfParts<V, ?>> {
    void something() {}
}

class GroupOfPartsDecorImpl<V> implements GroupOfParts<V, PartDecorator<V, PartImpl1<V>>> {
    @Override
    public Collection<PartDecorator<V, PartImpl1<V>>> getParts() {
        return null;
    }
}

interface GroupOfParts<V, P extends Part<V>> {
    Collection<P> getParts();
}

class PartDecorator<V, P extends Part<V>> implements Part<V> {
    @Override
    public V getId() {
        return null;
    }
}

class PartImpl1<V> implements Part<V> {
    @Override
    public V getId() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Since GOP is `GOP extends GroupOfParts<V, PartDecorator<V, ? extends Part<V>>>` and GroupOfPartsDecorImpl should be in the end `GroupOfParts<V, PartDecorator<V, Part<V>>` why this error shows up?

Comment: Can you give the exact message, including line numbers? see [mcve]

Comment: Error message is given at the top, and line here is 3, this part "`GroupOfPartsDecorImpl<V>`> getInstance()"

Comment: Eclipse states `Bound mismatch: The type GroupOfPartsDecorImpl<V> is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <GOP extends GroupOfParts<V,PartDecorator<V,? extends Part<V>>>> of the type MainContainerGroupPartDecorator<V,GOP>`

Comment: you want to **edit** your question to add such information ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second generic parameter to `GroupOfParts` must be `PartDecorator<V, ? extends Part<V>>`. And since generics are invariant by default there can be no deviation from this. But `GroupOfPartsDecorImpl` uses `PartDecorator<V, PartImpl1<V>>`, which is not the same, so it doesn't compile.

You can solve this by making the second parameter covariant in the declaration of `MainContainerGroupPartDecorator`:

```
class MainContainerGroupPartDecorator<V, GOP extends GroupOfParts<V,
    ? extends PartDecorator<V, ? extends Part<V>>>> 
    extends BaseContainerGroupPartDecorator<V, GOP> {
```

(Basically changing `PartDecorator<V, ? extends Part<V>>` to `? extends PartDecorator<V, ? extends Part<V>>`)

Comment: could you please explain this? _And since generics are invariant by default there can be no deviation from this_

Comment: @zencv I'd refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p

Comment: This seems like solving the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @JornVernee one unrelated question: is it possible to have this kind of specification class `SubMainContainerGroupPartDecorator<V, P extends Part<V>> extends BaseContainerGroupPartDecorator<V, ? extends GroupOfParts<V, ? extends PartDecorator<V, P>>> {` -> so instead to specify GroupOfParts<> I specify Part<V>?

Comment: @bojanv55 No, a super type can not use any wildcards.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your bounded wildcard in the 3rd level of your 2nd generic `? extends Part<V>`. You may specify it by an additional generic `P`

```
class MainContainerGroupPartDecorator<V, P extends Part<V>, GOP extends GroupOfParts<V, PartDecorator<V, P>>>
    extends BaseContainerGroupPartDecorator<V, GOP>
{
    public static <V> MainContainerGroupPartDecorator<V,PartImpl1<V>, GroupOfPartsDecorImpl<V>> getInstance() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I already fixed it using this way, but I hoped there was an easier way than doing this...